# Issue with sending email using SendGrid module in a contact form

Tags: javascript, typescript, email, button, sendgrid

Problem:
I'm trying to create a contact form for a website where users can enter their name, email, and message. Upon clicking the "Send" button, the form data should be sent to a specific email address using the SendGrid module. However, I'm encountering an issue where the email is not being sent, and I receive the following error in my console:

Error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/send-email 404 (Not Found)
Card.tsx:58 Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)
```

Code:
Here's the client-side code for Card.tsx, which represents the contact form:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import cardcss from "./Card.module.css";
import axios from "axios";

interface CardProps {
  imageUrl: string;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

function Card(props: CardProps) {
  // State and ref initialization

  useEffect(() => {
    // Focus and selection logic
  }, []);

  const handleFocus = (event: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    // Handle focus event
  };

  const submitHandler = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Form data retrieval and preparation

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3000/send-email", contactData)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Received email request");
        // Handle success response
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        // Handle error response
      });
  };

  return (
    // JSX code for the contact form
  );
}

export default Card;
```

And here's the server-side code for server.js, responsible for handling the email sending:

```
const express = require("express");
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
const { resolve } = require("path-browserify");

// Set up SendGrid API key
sgMail.setApiKey("*****");

// Create Express app
const app = express();

// Middleware to parse JSON requests
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello, server!");
});

// Route to handle sending emails
app.post("/send-email", (req, res) => {
  // Extract form data

  const msg = {
    to: "****@gmail.com",
    from: "*****@gmail.com",
    subject: "Example Subject",
    text: `Name: ${Name}\nEmail: ${Email}\nMessage: ${Message}\nSubmit Button: ${submitbutton}`,
    html: `<p>Name: ${Name}</p><p>Email: ${Email}</p><p>Message: ${Message}</p><p>Submit Button: ${submitbutton}</p>`,
  };

  sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Email sent successfully" });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.toString());
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to send email" });
    });
});

// Set up fallback for path module
resolve.fallback = { path: require.resolve("path-browserify") };

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

The code for the entire contact page is available in Contact.tsx:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import contactcss from "./Contact.module.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import Card from "../../components/ui/Card";
import {
  faInstagram,
  faFacebook,
  faLinkedin,
  faDiscord,
} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import emaillogo from "../../resources/email-logo.png";

const Contact: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div className={contactcss.background}>
          <img
            className={contactcss.emaillogo}
            src={emaillogo}
            alt="Contact Us"
          />
          <div className={contactcss.contact}>Contact Us</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <Card
        title="We're keen to hear from you!"
        imageUrl="https://images.app.goo.gl/D6m6hHMnP1gjsKKV7"
        body=""
        /* onSubmitForm={submitFormHandler} */ // Placeholder comment
      />

      <div className={contactcss.whitebackground}>
        <div className={contactcss.socials}>
          <h1>Follow Our Socials</h1>
          <p className={contactcss.socialmedia}>
            Stay connected with GDSC USYD by following us on our social media
            channels:
          </p>
          <div>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gdscusyd/">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.instagram}
                icon={faInstagram}
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/gdsc.usyd">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.facebook}
                icon={faFacebook}
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://discord.com/channels/872033047652990986/872033047652990989">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.discord}
                icon={faDiscord}
              />
            </a>

            <a href="*****">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.linkedin}
                icon={faLinkedin}
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Additional Information:

- I have verified that the SendGrid API key is correctly set up.
- Both the client and server are running locally.
- The server is listening on port 3000, and the client is making a POST request to http://localhost:3000/send-email.

Expected Behavior:
Upon clicking the "Send" button in the contact form, the form data should be sent to the server, and the email should be delivered to the specified email address.

Actual Behavior:
After clicking the "Send" button, I receive a 404 error in the console, and the email is not sent.

What I've Tried:

- I have double-checked the server-side code and ensured that the /send-email route is properly defined.
- I have verified that the server is running and listening on the correct port (3000).
- I have confirmed that the form data is correctly retrieved and prepared before making the POST request.

Question:
What could be causing the 404 error when attempting to send the email using the SendGrid module? Is there something wrong with my code or configuration? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you open a terminal session and try to run `curl http://localhost:3000`, what response do you get?

Comment: I got "curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused"

Comment: Are you running your server in WSL, a docker container or a VM?

Comment: I am on a mac, I'm pretty sure I'm using Linux..how exactly do I check if I am using WSL, a docker container or a VM?